# python pandas: filter out rows with multiple conditions

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I need to fix a CSV file. When I read it via pandas it shows me just one column but it has multiple.

So I split the column:

`df = df['test_column'].str.split(' ', expand = True)`

and got 168 rows.

I changed the name of the columns:
`df.set_axis(list(range(1, 169)), axis = 1, inplace = True)`

I am currently looking each column if it is completely empty or it has value in it with:

```
a = 122 #just a column name
df = df[df[a].notnull()]
print(df[a].to_string())
```

The Problem here is, even the specific row is empty it still shows me. I assume there is just spaces (" ").

So how can do multiple conditions?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data for testing?

Comment: provide sample data for us to understand the issue.

Comment: I would like to do, but I am not sure how I can do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC replace all empty strings or spaces to missing values first:

```
#removed ' ', by default plitting by arbitrary space
df = df['test_column'].str.split(expand = True)
#starting columns by 1
df.columns += 1

df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)

a = 122 #just a column name
df = df[df[a].isna()]
print (df)
```

Comment: This works fo much better. Thanks a lot.

Is there a way I can filter two condition? empty and "-" column

Comment: Okey, i figured out. It works with:

df = df[(df[a].notnull()) & (df[a] != "-")]